# If any of B contains all of A, then count # of times A is in all of B

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sql, csv, string

**BACKGROUND:** Long time reader, first time poster. Looking for help using QGIS to score data in a CSV table that was yielded from processing the contiguous neighbors of every polygon from a file with over 750k features.

**VERSION:** 2.2 or 3.0

**GOAL:** an equation to run in Field Calculator

**DATA:** Column A (small string), Column B (long string), Column C (output of function, a small integer)

**NATURAL LANGUAGE ARTICULATION:** If any part of B contains all of A, then count all instances of all of A in all of B, output number of instances as integer to Column C

EXAMPLE

```
COLUMN A     COLUMN B                                              COLUMN C
---------    --------------------------------------------------    --------
Doe, John    Doe, John; Smith, John; Johnson, Harry; Doe, John;    2
```

Comment: Could you add a specific example into the question to clarify?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to add clarifications. It's not fair to those who would help you to force them to scan comments for critical information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a custom function.

Open 'Function Editor' tab in 'Field Calculator'. Create new file, name it. Paste this script into the editor.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction('auto', 'Custom')
def func(field_a, field_b, feature, parent):
    return field_b.count(field_a)
```

Click 'Load' button. Go back to 'Expression' tab and write this expression: (You should use double quotes for field, not 'A' or 'B')

```
func( "A" , "B" )
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Checking if A is in B can be done using regular expressions:

```
CASE WHEN regexp_match('QGIS ROCKS','\\sROCKS') > 0 
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

but the counting will probably require a custom function.

Answer (score 4):

We found a way to do this in Excel:

https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-words-in-a-cell

Generic formula:

```
=(LEN(text)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(text,word,"")))/LEN(word)
```

Specific formula for the example above:

```
=(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")))/LEN(A1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer QGIS versions, you can use array functions to achieve this. Convert the string to an array (with elements delimited by `;`), use an `array_foreach()` fuction with `trim()` to remove whitespaces at the beginning/end and than count how many times the content of `COLUMN A` is contained in the array.

Use this expression to do so:

```
array_count(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array ("COLUMN B",';'),
        trim(@element)),
    trim("COLUMN A")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, the introduction of array expressions in QGIS 3.0 ([Feature: New expression functions | Changelog for QGIS 3.0](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html?highlight=qgis#feature-new-expression-functions)) opened the door to a lot more data analysis without having to resort to writing custom functions.  In addition to the `array_foreach` and `array_count` combination already mentioned, combining `array filter` and `array_length` also works:

```
array_length(
  array_filter(
    string_to_array("ColumnB", ';'),
    trim(@element) = trim("ColumnA")
  )
)
```